# Why is a method defined in the Foundation module available when the module is not imported?

Tags: swift, import, module

In a single view application project for iOS, I am able to use the contains(_:) method of the String type defined in the Foundation module in the ViewController file where the Foundation module is not imported. Why is this possible? The only module imported in this file is the UIKit module. Is the definition of the contains(_:) method provided through the UIKit module indirectly? If it is, how?

ViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let s = "Hello"
        print(s.contains("H"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **Command + Click** on `UIKit` in your import line (in Xcode, of course) you will be taken to the definition for the `UIKit` module. The first line you'll see at the top of that file is this:

```
import Foundation
```

Since `Foundation` is imported by `UIKit`, you can use `Foundation` methods in your code without importing `Foundation` when you import `UIKit`. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, if your answer is right, how does it explain this piece of code in playground:

`import Accounts`

`let s = "Hello"`
`print(s.contains("H"))`

Accounts doesn't seem to import Foundation. Why is the contains method of the String type available in this case?

Comment: First, if my answer helped you, mark it as "correct". Then, apply the answer to any further questions (like your new one above) and see if you can figure out the answer yourself. And if you can't, then post a new question about the issue.